# Koin: How to get the same Instance accoding to a given key

Tags: android, dependency-injection, koin

I used `ViewModelProvider(this).get(myDataIdentifier, MyViewModel::class.java)` to get the same viewmodel for each identifier.

Now I want to use Koin for dependency injection but I can't figure out how to get this working.

I can inject data via `val viewModel by viewModel()` but where am I able to make sure to get the same instance, identified by `myDataIdentifier`? I can't wrap my head around qualifier, parameter,....

Sorry, maybe this is a dumb question and i just overlooked something.

Answer (score 0):

Try with named components, name your viewmodel (this may now need to be a singleton?)

```
val myModule = module {
    viewModel(named("myViewModel")) { MyViewModel() }
}

...

val viewModel: MyViewModel by viewModel(named("myViewModel"))
```

https://engineering.bigshyft.com/koin-2-0-for-android/

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.

If I understand this correctly this approach assumes that I know all possible values in advance and provide them as named variants in 'myModule'.

But if I want to display data in a RecyclerView and each data item has a unique ID which I do not know but which I want to use to reference the ViewModel, then this is not possible, is it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve by injecting viewmodels based on values from a recyclerview, a viewmodel itself shouldn't be constrained to a specific object or set of values but instead be recreate-able and interchangeable between items for that view. 
Each viewmodel in the recycler could have the ID of the object it is created from then that ID can be later used to query a database or a list of something in order to create subsequent viewmodels for a different view...